# How can i put a check on one integer so that the if i run the code again it will not detect the value?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am converting the Chinese date to Gregorian, the code i have run perfectly fine for the first time replace the date but when i run it again it changes the date again.I have found the error but need to put a check on a integer variable so that next time it will not detect the variable value to change the date.

This is the Chinese date : 平成29年度
Perfect result after first run: 平成2017年度
If some one mistakenly run the code then dates changes to : 平成200817年度

The code matches these three character 平成29 and change the dates.

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
      Options.Pagination = False
      Dim Heisei As Integer
      Dim Gregorian As Integer
      Heisei = 20
      Gregorian = 2008
      Dim C As Integer
Do Until C = 50
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Heisei
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Gregorian
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Heisei = Heisei + 1
    Gregorian = Gregorian + 1
    C = C + 1
Loop
```

If i run the code mistakenly again & again, the code will check the "Heisei" value is 20 or 2017. So that the code will not check for this 平成20. But for the 平成2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following lines to use wildcards, so as to find anything but a digit that follows the year number.

```
.Text = ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Heisei & "([!0-9]*)"
.Replacement.Text = ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Gregorian & "\1"
.MatchWildcards = True
```

Comment: What if this symbol 年 'ChrW(24180)' not apper with the date, what if some other symbol appears with it.!  (For example :末,度 ) i think you understand my point.

Comment: @M Ahad - You can use wildcards then.